# Congruence (number theory) problem

Tags: number-theory, congruences

The problem is: $1007^{33} + 33^{1007}≡x(mod 5)$

I started with

$1007≡2(mod 5)$ => $1007^{33}≡2^{33}(mod 5)$ => $1007^{33}≡2(mod 5)$

but I am stuck with the other part

I can't find $33^{1007}≡x(mod 5)$ because I can't calculate $33^{1007}$ and I tried with going step by step and trying to guess the solution but I got:

$33≡3(mod5), 33^2≡4(mod5), 33^3≡2(mod5), 33^4≡1(mod 5)...$ So I have no idea what to do.

Also, even if I find it, what should I do next?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If $33^4 \equiv 1$, then $33^{4k}\equiv 1^k$.

Comment: How did you handle $2^{33} \mod 5$?  How did you get $2^{33} \equiv 2 \mod 5$ ?  You'd doe $3^{1007}$ the same way.  (By the way, do you know Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: Yes, I read about the theorem. With your help I realized that $33^{1007}≡2 (mod 5)$ and similarly $1007^{33}≡2(mod 5)$ with FLT ($ a^{p-1}≡1(mod p), (a;p)=1$) The other theorems also allow the following: if $a≡b(mod m)$ and $c≡ d(mod m)$ $=>$ $a+c≡(b+d)(mod m)$ so I think that the result is $x=4$ and I hope I'm right :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Fermat's little theorem, $33^4\equiv1\pmod 5$, and so

$$33^{1007} \equiv 33^{251\cdot 4} \cdot 33^{3} \equiv 1\cdot 2 \pmod 5$$

---

I think you may also wish to know about repeated squaring. To calculate $33^{1007} \bmod 5$,

$$\begin{align*}
33^1 &\equiv 3 \pmod 5\\
33^2 &\equiv 3^2 \equiv4\\
33^4 &\equiv 4^2 \equiv1\\
33^8 &\equiv 1^2 \equiv 1\\
33^{16} &\equiv 1^2 \equiv 1\\
33^{32} &\equiv 1^2 \equiv 1\\
33^{64} &\equiv 1^2 \equiv 1\\
33^{128} &\equiv 1^2 \equiv 1\\
33^{256} &\equiv 1^2 \equiv 1\\
33^{512} &\equiv 1^2 \equiv 1\\
\end{align*}$$

This gets trivial only because it is $\bmod 5$, and so after the fourth power, every $33^{2^k} \equiv 1$. For other modulus, the results may be more interesting.

And to obtain $33^{1007} \bmod 5$,

$$\begin{align*}
33^{1007} &\equiv 33^{512+256+128+64+32+8+4+2+1}\\
&\equiv 1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot4\cdot3\\
&\equiv2 \pmod 5
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Yes, I read about the Fermat's Little Theorem: $a^{p-1}≡1 (mod p), (a;p)=1$ and I found that  if $a≡b(mod m)$ and $c≡ d(mod m)$ $=>$ $a+c≡(b+d)(mod m)$  and it was easy to calculate the x :) Thank you very much!